# How to float the navbar header to the right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I be able to float the navbar header (which contains logo) to the right section in Bootstrap. Here is my example:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top BKoodakBold" id="topMenu">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li><a href="aboutus.php">About Gooyanet&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-equalizer"></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="signin.php">Login to your account &nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="prove.php">Register at Gooyanet &nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-registration-mark"></span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.gooyanet.com">Gooyanet</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: use `.pull-right`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following class with your div like

```
<div class="pull-left collapse navbar-collapse"> </div>
<div class="pull-right navbar-header"></div>
```

Comment: Please check this link to see what will be wrong if I add this. http://gooyanet.com/

Comment: That's it ,you made it :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the [`pull-right` helper class](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-floats) to the element you want to float right. This is your `.navbar-header`, in this case. Please see the following demo.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top BKoodakBold" id="topMenu">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li><a href="aboutus.php">About Gooyanet&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-equalizer"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="signin.php">Login to your account &nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="prove.php">Register at Gooyanet &nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-registration-mark"></span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-header pull-right">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.gooyanet.com">Gooyanet</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please check this link to see what will be wrong if I add this. http://gooyanet.com/

Comment: It *is* on the right side on that page. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code. I've used class="navbar-header navbar-right" on the header.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top BKoodakBold" id="topMenu">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header navbar-right">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.gooyanet.com">Gooyanet</a>
        </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="aboutus.php">About Gooyanet&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-equalizer"></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="signin.php">Login to your account &nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="prove.php">Register at Gooyanet &nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-registration-mark"></span></a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The output will look like the following. Hope it's what you're looking for :)

[Screen Shot of the Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoVf7.png)